# What is the alternative for Compose in react-Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have been trying to use multiple graphql() enhancers at once, but compose seems not to be working. I have tried a load of different imports from different libraries, still nothing. Does any know any fix? The data is not being passed from graphl() to my component props, so I'm getting an error that reads **`Cannot destructure property 'loading' of 'data' as it is undefined.`**

Here's my component:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
   
// import {compose} from 'redux'
import { flowRight as compose } from 'lodash'
import { graphql} from 'react-apollo'
import {getAuthorsQuery, addBookMutation} from './queries/query'




const AddBook = (props) => {
  
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name:'',
    genre:'',
    authorId:''
  })

  const {name, genre, authorId} = formData
  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

 const displayAuthors = () => {
   let data = props.data
   const {loading} = data

   if(loading){
   return (<option>Loading Authors</option>) 
   } else{
      return data.authors.map(author => {
       return (<option key={author.id} value={author.id}>{author.name}</option>)
      })
   }
  }

  const submitForm = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(formData);
   
  }

  return (
    <form id="add-book" onSubmit={e => submitForm(e)}>
      <div className="field">
        <label>Book name:</label>
        <input 
        type="text"
        onChange={e => onChange(e)} 
        name="name"
        value={name}
         />
      </div>

      <div className="field">
        <label>Genre:</label>
        <input 
        name="genre"
        value={genre}
        type="text" 
       onChange={e => onChange(e)}
       />
      </div>

      <div className="field">
        <label>Author:</label>
        <select
        name="authorId"
        value={authorId}
        onChange={e => onChange(e)}
        >
        <option>Select Author</option>
        {displayAuthors()}
        </select>
      </div>
        
      <button>+</button>
   
    </form>
  )
}

// export default graphql(getAuthorsQuery)(AddBook)

export default compose(
  graphql(getAuthorsQuery, {name: "getAuthorsQuery"}),
  graphql(addBookMutation, {name:"addBookMutation"})
)(AddBook)
```

And my query:

```
   import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'

const getBooksQuery = gql`
{
 books{
     name,
     id
 }
}
`

const getAuthorsQuery = gql`
{
 authors{
     name,
     id
 }
}
`

const addBookMutation = gql`
mutation{
  addBook(name:"", genre:"", authorId:""){
    name,
    id
  }
}
`
export {getAuthorsQuery, getBooksQuery, addBookMutation}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're providing a `name` option for both your HOCs, so the data will be available under those prop names:

```
props.getAuthorsQuery.loading
```

That said, the HOCs are deprecated -- you should probably be using the newer hooks API.

Comment: I don't see deprecation warning in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#graphqlquery-configcomponent)

Comment: @HMR [Docs for ApolloClient 3.0](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/react/hoc/)

Comment: @MuhammedA.O If you're trying to learn the new hooks API I would start with [this resource](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and then read about the Apollo API [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/data/queries/). Work through a couple of examples and then if you hit a roadblock and can't find any similar questions on SO, feel free to throw one up. Or hit up the spectrum channel.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of useQuery hook from apollo and execute the queries like

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

import React,{useState} from 'react'

// import {compose} from 'redux'
import { flowRight as compose } from 'lodash'
import {getAuthorsQuery, addBookMutation} from './queries/query'


const AddBook = (props) => {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name:'',
    genre:'',
    authorId:''
  })
  const  authors = useQuery(getAuthorsQuery):
  const bookMutation = useQuery(addBookMutation);

  ... rest of code here


}

export default AddBook;
```

Comment: Thank you. could you please show me how i would implement the variables created using the  useQuery function. thanks once again.

Comment: The returned values will be the values for getAuthorsQuery and addBookMutation, you can name it anything you want and use them in your code

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue. I got useQuery and useMutation methods to work together and did not have to use compose. I am still new to gql so if you spot any bad practice or a tip, I would love to hear:

```
const authorsData = useQuery(authorsQuery)

//addBook takes args and send data to db when triggered in submitHandler
const [addBook] = useMutation(addBookMutation); 
  
const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(name, genre, author)
        addBook({
            variables: {
                name: name,
                genre: genre,
                authorId: author
            },
            refetchQueries: [{ query: bookList }]
        })
    }
```